# how to delete site, project, approval workflow, coordination space, partner card, custom attribute, etc?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

we're testing BIM 360, seems OOTB functions cannot delete the followings, just wonder if it's doable via API, Forge, even unsupported method.

1. site -> for instance, i accidently created a new site, how to delete it by myself?
2. project -> inactive or archived
3. approval workflow in Docs Review
4. coordination space
5. partner card -> how to delete it once i added 3rd party app?
6. custom attribute -> how to delete it once i created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

re. #1 - if you created a new account yourself, I assume you are talking about a trial site. If so, the site will be deleted 30 days after the trial expires.

re. #2, #3 - no API

re. #4 - if this is about stop automatic trigger of new model set, maybe you can use this one to disable automatic?

https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/mc-modelset-service-v3-disable-model-set-versions-PATCH/

re. #5 - in UI, each card has a "setting" gear >> Hide card
This will put back a card to the library list.

re. #6 - with the latest enhancement to project based custom attribute definition, there is a delete function. deleting API is still to come.

Note: This new enhancement apply only to the newly added project.

https://blogs.autodesk.com/bim360-release-notes/2021/03/23/bim-360-docs-search-filter-and-custom-attributes-enhancements-march-23-2021/

Comment: too bad that all testing stuff are accumulated and cause confusion, do hope there's unsupported way to delete those.

Comment: If you need a development and testing environment, you can request a development environment. Instructions here: 
 https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/2017/08/31/bim-360-acc-account-for-development/

It's better to separate production environment from development.

Comment: thanks Mikako, we actually use ADN licenses, looks like software request form is exactly the same, i mean our ADN licenses are already in development environment, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it will be the same.  ADN one will be longer.